# Node nested promises with Resolve values

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have three async functions that should work after each other.

**my code:**

```js
let companyNameCheck = req.body.name;
let companyNameCheckPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    generalHelper.companyExistsHelper(res, companyNameCheck, reject);
    resolve();
});

companyNameCheckPromise.then((data) => {
    // CHECK IF LOGO EXISTS
    if (!req.files)
        return res.status(400).send({
            code: errorHandling.FILE_UPLOAD_CODE,
            message: errorHandling.FILE_UPLOAD_MESSAGE
        });

    //FILE UPLOAD AND GETTING THE FILE NAME WITH PROMISE
    let logo = req.files.logo;
    data = fileHelper.fileUploadHelper(res, logo, "companies_logos");
    console.log(data); //THIS RETURN THE DATA
    return data;
});

companyNameCheckPromise.then((data) => {
    console.log(data); // THIS RETURN UNDEFIND
});
```

**Problem:**

I want to pass value from the first `then` to the second `then`.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to make a global variable and assign `Resolve` to this global variable but still it is not a solution.

Comment: You are branching off`companyNameCheckPromise` with two independent `then`s. To do things sequentially, form a single chain with `companyNameCheckPromise.then(...).then(...);`

Answer (score 0):

`companyNameCheckPromise` needs to return a Promise:

```
companyNameCheckPromise.then((data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
    resolve(data); // do not return it
  });
});
```